# Lightswitch: Load operation failed for query 'GetAuthenticationInfo'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

Here is my scenario:

Solution is made up of two projects - a LS app and a RIA Services project. The RIA services are connecting to remote Web Service which is residing in other domain. These RIA services were added as Data Sources into LS app. When I run this app as Desktop app, everything works. The correct credential handling is implemented in domain services and no errors occured through final testing.

Then I was asked to publish this app on IIS. I use the zip package method. I still can't get it working. I am facing strange behavior.

this is the message that sometimes appears in browser when I run the app:

> Load operation failed for query 'GetAuthenticationInfo'. The remote
>   server returned an error: NotFound.

thats all, then the default error message is displayed, no piece of GUI appears.

when I look in Fiddler, I can see these two errors:

> 404:
>   /LsApp/Web/Microsoft-LightSwitch-Security-ServerGenerated-Implementation-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/GetAuthenticationInfo
>
> 404:
>   /Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client;component/screens/screenpresentation/internalframework/resources/resources/x.png

I found on internet that some people had this too and that they solved it by repairing .NET installation or by setting up the server properly for running Lightswitch apps. I did all the recommended things - I patched the server, I reinstalled .NET, I installed LS Runtime prerequisities, I checked all the recommended settings of IIS - but no luck.

Please, if you are aware of the reason of this behaviour, I will be very gladfull if you share your knowledge.

Thank you.

EDIT: because the remote service is a NAV Dynamics Web Service which is hosted directly in Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Server.exe process without IIS I installed a windows service which serves clientaccesspolicy.xml ([Freddys Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/28/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-silverlight-3.aspx)) and the problem is is still present. So I don't think it's a cross-domain related problem.

Comment: We have two IIS servers, one for test and one for production. On the test environment, the LightSwitch app works fine, but on the prod environment, I get the exact same errors as you. Did you ever find a solution?